# SSMS Connect to remote SQL instance with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms, errors, connectivity, windows-authentication

I have a remote SQL instance

**(Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU3) (KB4458871) - 13.0.5216.0 (X64)**

I can connect to the instance fine locally on the box through SSMS using both Windows and SQL Authentication. I can connect to the instance fine remotely using SQL Authentication. However I am unable to connect to the box using Windows Authentication from anywhere on the domain.

I get the following error message which seems to mean it can be several things but nothing which describes my specific issue:

[image]

The same error happens when using the server name and IP address. I do not have this issue with any other SQL instances on the domain, just this one. The fact I can connect using SQL Authentication suggests it is not network or firewall related and is an issue with the configuration on this specific VM / instance. Nothing gets logged to the SQL error logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the server changed name after initial SQL setup? Did you verify SPN's for the server machine and SQL instance?